# How to save to XML using dataset

Tags: xml, database

I am using a sql database to save the data of a simple note taking application, using dataset and gui is binded with database. Simple work.
Using SQL is useless here, I want to save the data to a simple XML file instead of SQL using the same dataset.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and programming in C# .Net 4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dataset of a single table to XML

```
private void SingleTableToXml()
{
    DataSet myDS = getDataSet();

    // To write out the contents of the DataSet as XML,
    // use a file name to call the WriteXml method of the DataSet class
    myDS.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("filename.xml"), XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
}
```

if you have more than one table in the dataset, say it a master-detail relationship, then the method is exactly the same. Just make sure to create the DataRelation between tables and set the relation `Nested` property to true as in the following code

```
//Get the primary key column from the master table
DataColumn primarykey = myDS.Tables["Categories"].Columns["CategoryID"];
//Get the foreign key column from the detail table
DataColumn foreignkey = myDS.Tables["Products"].Columns["CategoryID"];

//Assign a relation
DataRelation relation = myDS.Relations.Add(primarykey, foreignkey);

//Ask ADO.NET to generate nested XML nodes
relation.Nested = true;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: ok, written to XML how will i load from it next time? ReadXml?

Comment: Yes. ReadXml is your way. You can find examples for every override on the [MSDN reference page](http://bit.ly/a53DOL). Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

What i use is:

```
        private void buttonSaveXML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveFile = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFile.Filter = "XML Files|*.xml";
        saveFile.Title = "Save a Xml File";
        saveFile.ShowDialog();
        if (saveFile.FileName != "")
        {
            FileStream fs =
                (FileStream)saveFile.OpenFile();
            DataSet.WriteXml(fs);
        }
    {
```

DataSet is the Dataset I use and It is a good idea to make a separate button to make it easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify your programming environment.  Assuming you're using .NET....

Use the [WriteXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.writexml%28VS.71%29.aspx) method of the dataSet.

There's an article here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233698%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2010 and programming in C# .Net 4.0

Answer (score 1):

Here are good example of generate XML from dataset

```
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataColumn dc;
    DataRow dr;
    ds.DataSetName = "products";
    dt.TableName = "product";

    dc = new DataColumn("product_id");
    dt.Columns.Add(dc);

    dc = new DataColumn("product_name");
    dt.Columns.Add(dc);

    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["product_id"] = 1;
    dr["product_name"] = "Monitor";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["product_id"] = 2;
    dr["product_name"] = "Mouse";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["product_id"] = 3;
    dr["product_name"] = "KeyBoard";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    string strXML= ds.GetXml();

    System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("datasetxml.xml"));
    sw.WriteLine(strXML);
    sw.Close();
```